# Context menu option to append a prefix to filename and update modification date

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, context-menu

I'm trying to make a context menu item to add a # prefix to selected files names and update their modification time.
this is the used command:

```
cmd /c copy /b \"%1\" +,, & ren \"%1\" \"#%1\"
```

`copy /b \"%1\" +,,` part will update files modification date and its working fine.
but the `ren \"%1\" \"#%1\"` part is not working;
after aiding `& pause` to end of the command this is the cmd output:

```
1 file(s) copied.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

i guess its because instead of `\"#%1\"` i need something that will present *"#filename.extension"* while `\"#%1\"` presets *"#D:\filename.extension"* and thus I'm asking for your help.

this is the context menu reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Qtag]
"MUIVerb"="Q Tag"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Qtag\Command]
@="cmd /c copy /b \"%1\" +,, & ren \"%1\" \"#%1\""
```

Comment: try `cmd /c copy /b \"%~1\" +,, & ren \"%~1\" \"#%~nx1\"`

Comment: LotPings \"%~1\" wont work though \"%1\" works and nor \"#%~nx1\" or \"#%nx1\" works (\"#%nx1\" renames file to #nx1)

Comment: Insert the way you create the context menu into your question. Quoting/escaping several levels gets complicated.